# How to show Angular controller data based on specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to show the data from my angular controller based on a specific value, which in this case is the days of the week.  Here is my controller:

```
app.controller("ExerciseCtrl", function($scope){
    var exercise_arr = [
        {
            name: "Bicep Curl",
            weight: 30,
            day: "Monday"
        },
        {
            name: "Bench Press",
            weight: 140,
            day: "Tuesday"
        },
        {
            name: "Squats",
            weight: 140,
            day: "Thursday"
        }
    ];

    $scope.exercises = exercise_arr;
});
```

Now in my HTML, I will have a tab for each day of the week.  How do I go about only showing the controller data's day with the corresponding tab for the day of the week?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#">Sunday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Monday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tuesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wednesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thursday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Friday</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Saturday</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-controller="ExerciseCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="exercise in exercises">
        <li>
            {{exercise}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So what I want in the end is that when I click on the Monday tab, I only want the controller data that has the day value of Monday, etc.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you please share your code where you got stuck while working on this logic?

Comment: I kinda miss working with angular, if you can wrap the `<ul>` in the controller  you can do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sbLuodqv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use filter like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var exercise_arr = [
        {
            name: "Bicep Curl",
            weight: 30,
            day: "Monday"
        },
        {
            name: "Bench Press",
            weight: 140,
            day: "Tuesday"
        },
        {
            name: "Squats",
            weight: 140,
            day: "Thursday"
        }
    ];

    $scope.exercises = exercise_arr;
    $scope.setFilter = function(filter){
      $scope.filterDay = filter;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-repeat="item in exercises"><a href="#" ng-click="setFilter(item.day)">{{item.day}}</a></li>
</ul>

<div >
    <ul ng-repeat="exercise in exercises | filter:{day:filterDay}">
        <li>
            {{exercise.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```